# Access violation when using TcxGridColumn with property BlobEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress, access-violation, vcl, delphi-xe4

Application have **TcxGrid** that contains some columns. One column has property **BlobEdit** with **BlobEditKind** == **bekMemo**. When I open **BlobEdit** and leave form (by Alt+Tab or just click any place out of form), I get exceprion **Access Violation** with text "Project Project1.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00748c1c: read of address 0x00000000'".

When I tried to debug it, I found that exception was created first in *TcxCustomEdit.CMEnter*.

How can I avoid this problem?

I`m using **Delphi XE4 Update 1** and **DevExpress 13.2.2**.

Comment: Your best bet is to log a ticket with the Dev Express support. They are very good. Go to the dev express site and click on Support. Then chose "my questions". You can log in and ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated DevExpress and problem was solved.